# How to get Record ID without Hardcoding it

Tags: soql, javascript, custom-button, query, ajax-toolkit

Can you guys give me an idea on how I can get the Record type id without hard coding it because it may cause an error when it is transferred to another production. This is in a custom button.

This is My code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js")}{!REQUIRESCRIPT("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js")}


jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" />');

// identify the record <br>
var m = new sforce.SObject("Matter__c"); 
m.id = "{!Matter__c.Id}"; 

// make the field change 
m.Status__c = "Sent to GICO";<br> 
m.RecordTypeId = "012f000000090iL";<br>
// save the change<br>
result = sforce.connection.update([m]);<br>
//if(result.success == 'true'){<br>
  //notification<br>
toastr.options = {<br>
  "closeButton": true,<br>
  "debug": false,<br>
  "newestOnTop": false,<br>
  "progressBar": false,<br>
  "positionClass": "toast-top-center",<br>
  "preventDuplicates": false,<br>
  "onclick": null,<br>
  "showDuration": "3000",<br>
  "hideDuration": "1000",<br>
  "timeOut": "5000",<br>
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",<br>
  "showEasing": "swing",<br>
  "hideEasing": "linear",<br>
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",<br>
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"<br>
}

toastr["info"]("Sent Successfully")<br>
//refresh page<br>
  window.location.reload();<br>
//}else{<br>
// alert(result.message);<br>
//}<br>
```

I am still a beginner in Apex Programming. By TL told me to use this code but after many hours of searching the web on how to use it, I still can't find an answer.

```
var rt = sforce.connection.query('select id, name from recordtype where developername='GICO');
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I see with your query is that you use the same type of quotes twice. If your query string is declared with single quotes (`'`), then use double-quotes for your filter (`"`), and vice versa.

```
var soql1 = 'SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = "GICO"',
    soql2 = "SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'GICO'";
```

You can also escape them and use the same type, but I would say in general the above is preferable.

```
var soql1 = 'SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = \'GICO\'',
    soql2 = "SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = \"GICO\"";
```

---

Once you have a working query string, you can retrieve the Id you seek as follows:

```
var recordId = sforce.connection.query(/*query*/).getArray('records')[0].Id;
```

Comment: Well with my original code. I am Hardcoding the Record Type Id which is a wrong approach. So my question is how can I get the Record Type ID without hardcoding it.

Comment: I tried using this.

var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Matter__c' AND DeveloperName='GICO' "); 

records = query.getArray('records'); 

m.RecordTypeId = records[0].Id;

Comment: @JMDF And...did it work? Do you have an error message to share?

Comment: it throws an error " cannot read propery 'id' of undefined " @AdrianLarson

Comment: So it sounds like your query didn't return any records. Are you sure it should? Have you run that query in the Query Editor, or any other SOQL tool?

Comment: I've change my query where in I removed the DeveloperName = 'Gico' because I don't have any data in it and it was sent successfully. Thanks man. Really appreciated your help.

Comment: One last question. Can you please explain to me what this part of the code you've given me do. 

.getArray('records')[0].Id;

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Record Type Id based on API Name of record type and object instead of hard-coding Id.

```
var query = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType="Object_Name" AND DeveloperName="RecordType_Name");
records = query.getArray('records'); 
var recordTypeId = records[0].Id;
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me on how this code works. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am actually not sure. I just assumed that the code he's given is correct. My Bad